# c++ segmentation fault and Trace/breakpoint trap when using Dynamic memory allocation

Tags: c++

I am practicing Dynamic memory allocation in C++. I wanna enter some word which length is less than 10, and when I enter "-1", it will print the word I have entered before.

But when I enter more than three words, it will give me an Trace/breakpoint trap or segmentation fault. I use gdb-peda to check my code, it said "double free detected in tcache 2", I think the problem is the "delete" part in my code, but I dont know how to correct it.

[the gdb-peda reply](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X5CR8.png)

this is my code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
using namespace std;

int counter = 0;    //be used to count how many times we have entered
char **ins();

int main() {
    auto dict = ins();    //Total list

    for ( int i = 0; i < counter; i++ ) {
        for ( int j = 0; j < 10; j++ ) {
            if ( *( *( dict + i ) + j ) == '\0' )    //if the word is null,print the word and go to next word
                break;
            cout << *( *( dict + i ) + j );
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    for ( int i = 0; i < counter; i++ )
        delete[] dict[i];    //delete the total list

    system( "pause" );
    return 0;
}

char **ins() {

    auto dict = new char *[1]();    //total list
    auto cpdict = new char *[1]();    //copy list

    while ( 1 ) {

        auto word = new char[10]();    //a list be used to store the entered word  (length<10)

        cout << "input word: ";
        cin.get( word, 10, '\n' );    //get the entered word in the list
        if ( word[0] == '-' && word[1] == '1' ) {    //if enter "-1" , delete the copy list and return the total list
            delete[] cpdict;
            return dict;
        }
        counter++;    //plus one of the times of entering

        delete[] dict;    //delete the old total list
        auto dict = new char *[counter]();    //create a new total list, the lenth is one more than the old total list
        for ( int i = 0; i < counter - 1; i++ ) *( dict + i ) = *( cpdict + i );    //copy the stuffs in old copy list to new total list
        *( dict + counter - 1 ) = word;    //copy the word we just enter into total list

        delete[] cpdict;    //delter the old copy list
        auto cpdict = new char *[counter]();    //create a new copy list
        for ( int i = 0; i < counter; i++ ) *( cpdict + i ) = *( dict + i );    //copy the stuffs in new total list to new copy list

        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore( numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n' );
    }
}
```

My imagine input and output is like:

```
input word: aaa
input word: bbb
input word: ccc
input word: ddd
input word: -1
```

output:

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
ddd
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, try not to use `using namespace std;`.

I have also found a memory leak in your code. You allocate the `word` pointer every iteration but did you make sure to delete it when you get to the next iteration? What you need to do is, delete the `word` buffer at the end of the iteration. Plus you also have two variables `dict` and `cpdict` which you allocate memory for no reason, delete them later on in the `while` loop only to assign a new block of memory. Try to avoid unwanted allocations as it'll only slow things down. Frankly its hard to debug your code (mainly because your working with a lot of pointers) so ill show you a *good* implementation (ill add comments to show important notes).

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
//using namespace std;    <-- Dont use this, ever.

/**
 * Lets create a struct named Word so that its easier to work with and debug.
 * Also we can use a normal stack allocated array because we know the maximum word size beforehand and it has the added
 * benifit of not needing to deallocate it at the end of each iteration.
 */
struct Word {
    char mWord[10];
};

int counter = 0;    //be used to count how many times we have entered
Word* ins();

int main() {
    auto dict = ins();    //Total list

    for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
        // Here you dont have to worry about null terminations as itll automatically gets terminated because the 
        // default values of all the elements in the word array is 0.
        std::cout << dict[i].mWord;
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    // Here you just have to delete the array itself.
    delete[] dict;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

Word* ins() {
    Word* dict = nullptr;   // The array of words. Dont allocate anything here because its unwanted.

    while (1) {
        Word word;  // Instantiate the struct.

        std::cout << "input word: ";
        std::cin.get(word.mWord, 10, '\n');    //get the entered word in the list
        if (word.mWord[0] == '-' && word.mWord[1] == '1') {    //if enter "-1" , delete the copy list and return the total list
            return dict;
        }
        counter++;    //plus one of the times of entering

        // The instruction pointer came here because there was a new word inserted which is not "-1" so we need to
        // add it to the array. Lets first allocate a new buffer.
        Word* cdict = new Word[counter];

        // If we had an array before, lets copy the old content to the new buffer using memcpy() and delete the old block.
        if (dict)
        {
            memcpy(cdict, dict, sizeof(Word) * (static_cast<size_t>(counter) - 1));
            delete[] dict;
        }

        // Now we can add the new word to buffer.
        cdict[counter - 1] = word;

        // Now lets assign the buffer to the main array pointer. Remember, we dont delete the buffer as this buffer
        // contains the actual data. We will have to delete it at the end when the program terminates.
        dict = cdict;

        std::cin.clear();
        std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    }
}
```

Try not to use raw pointers as it'll make it harder to understand what's going on and it'll be a lot painful to debug in these types of errors. The C++ standard library provides a lot of nice options like `std::string`, `std::vector` and use [Smart Pointers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/smart-pointers-modern-cpp?view=msvc-160) whenever possible.

Comment: I learned a lot, really appreciate for your reply :D